# screen blanking randomly

Tags: multiple-monitors, external-monitor

On my Ubuntu 22.04 system, after some days of using the system without issues, my screens blank without reason after a very short delay of not using the system (half a minute?).

Moving the mouse or typing activates them again immediately, but it's annoying. Delay is set to 8 minutes.

My setup:

- 09:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP108 [GeForce GT 1030] (rev a1)
- proprietary ubuntu driver (version 515.65.01)
- 2 screens:

  1. AOC 32'' monitor, 2560x1440@74.97 Hz; connected with DVI-to-HDMI
  2. Sichuang Changhong Corporation 42'' (Chiq) TV; connected with HDMI
- gdm on X11

Additionally, my second monitor (TV) loses its signal from time to time, until I unplug and replug the hdmi cable.

Any clue on both issues? Don't know if they are related.

Comment: I am having a similar problem, and I have Ubuntu 22.04 and an NVIDIA GT 1070. I'm thinking the graphics driver might have some issue. The problem has been coming and going for months (possibly since before upgrading to 22.04). Restarting the computer makes it disappear...